# Memcache not saving entity list on Java AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, serialization, memcached, objectify

I want to save a List of an entity kind to memcache. The entity is using objectify annotation. So to save my list to memcache I do

```
MemcacheService syncCache = MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService("food");
syncCache.setErrorHandler(ErrorHandlers.getConsistentLogAndContinue(Level.INFO));
syncCache.put("foods",foodList);//foodList = ArrayList of Objectify entity
syncCache.put("timesaved",new DateTime());
```

I keep getting error saying that my entity is not serializable

```
java.io.NotSerializableException:'com.company.data.Food'
```

Any ideas how I might get this to work? `foodList` is the result of a query. I just want to save the result of that query to memcache.

Comment: Have you implemented the Serializable interface in the com.company.data.Food object?

Comment: Could you post code where `foodList` is created?